# Fantasy manga where a man raises three female slaves where it sounds like he'll exploit them, but he's actually helping raise them

Tags: story-identification, manga, slavery

Last week, when searching for a story-id (I don't remember which), I came upon a tale, which I read through all of the currently available parts, and then promptly seem to have lost the links. I think there were about 17 chapters of about a dozen pages each at the time I read it. I don't remember the site exactly. It definitely looked like Japanese manga style, predominantly black and white, although each chapter ended with an animated pixel art gift of a young girl making snarky comments about all of the "lolis" reading the book. The basic premise is as above. The main character, male, acquires three young slaves of mixed race (I think there were elven and demonic aspects to them) with narration that sound like he plans to sexually exploit them, and then dump them, only for the rest of the chapter to show that his words are actually referring to the measures he's taking to ensure that they grow up as civilized young ladies, things like "When I get them home, I will strip all of their clothes off!" only to then show that he's dressed them in properly fitted clothing. I think another one had him talking about how he was going to stuff them full of manly juices, only to have the next panels involving him sitting them down to a sumptious meal including a lot of meat.

I think the first dozen or so chapters had them as children, with the last few having them apparently the age of teenagers (albeit that I think the narration indicated that they just aged quickly). I remember that one girl (dark haired) excelled in cooking and other household duties and was usually the quietest, another (I think also dark haired) was particularly gifted in magic (apparently as a result of their demonic heritage) and was the one who made most of the sexual references in her speech (although initially it was implied that she was just repeating what she'd heard in her early days of slavery), and the third was blonde and buxom, and extremely lazy, noted to primarily enjoy eating and sleeping, although she was also apparently an adventurer who roamed outside of town and killed monsters.

The art style was stylized, but detailed, and was naughty (panty-shots, a few bits of bare chests) but nothing explicit was shown (although I do remember now that the second girl learned about her demonic heritage with a living device with tentacles that she inserted just off-camera, implied to be used by inserting it into her genitals), and the central gag was that the protagonist never actually took advantage of them (although it was kind of ambiguous as to whether he never intended to, that he just never followed through on it, or that he was just waiting for them to be old enough).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the *[Dorei wo Choukyou shite Harem Tsukuru](https://myanimelist.net/manga/150788)* series. The original is from [the artist's pixiv](https://www.pixiv.net/en/artworks/98084601). The animated gifs you mentioned are added by the translators.

[image]

I believe the "main series" is risque but not directly sexual, mostly focusing on misunderstandings, but there are also unambiguously sexual versions as well - I think restricted to the artist's supporters.